# PostgreSQL run queries in parallel

Tags: arrays, postgresql, window-functions, recursive-query

I'm trying to create a query/view that performs a hierarchy calculation on a group of subjects, and returns common ancestors within 3 generations. I have successfully ran this on a single subject at a time, and would like to be able to do it over a complete table. Below is the relevant subquery, when executed it returns common ancestors from ANY subject (siblings return parents), the desired result this to be run over ancestors common to EACH subject (an inbred individual). How do I input multiple values, run a query on the individual values, then retrieve the multiple individual outputs traced back to the original inputs?

```
WITH d1 AS (
   WITH RECURSIVE nodes(sub, parentid, parentname, childid, childname, path, depth) AS (
           SELECT cats.dbid AS sub,
              r.parentid,
              p1.subject,
              r.childid,
              p2.subject,
              ARRAY[r.parentid] AS "array",
              1
             FROM pedigree_search r,
              pedigree p1,
              pedigree p2,
              cats
            WHERE r.childid = cats.dbid AND p1.dbid = r.parentid AND p2.dbid = r.childid
          UNION ALL
           SELECT cats.dbid AS sub,
              r.parentid,
              p1.subject,
              r.childid,
              p2.subject,
              nd.path || r.parentid,
              nd.depth + 1
             FROM pedigree_search r,
              pedigree p1,
              pedigree p2,
              nodes nd,
              cats
            WHERE r.childid = nd.parentid AND p1.dbid = r.parentid AND p2.dbid = r.childid AND nd.depth < 3
   )
   SELECT nodes.sub,
      nodes.parentid,
      nodes.parentname,
      nodes.childid,
      nodes.childname,
      nodes.path,
      nodes.depth
     FROM nodes
)
SELECT d1.sub,
  d1.parentid,
  d1.parentname,
  d1.childid,
  d1.childname,
  d1.path,
  d1.depth
 FROM d1
WHERE (d1.parentid IN ( SELECT d1_1.parentid
         FROM d1 d1_1
        GROUP BY d1_1.parentid
       HAVING count(d1_1.parentid) > 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is too convoluted to follow, but in principle it would look like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE anc AS (
      SELECT seed.p AS child,
             r.parent AS ancestor,
             1 AS level
      FROM relation AS r
         JOIN (VALUES (42),
                      (12),
                      ...
              ) AS seed(p)
            ON r.child = seed.p
   UNION
      SELECT a.child,
             r.parent,
             a.level + 1
      FROM relation AS r
         JOIN anc AS a
            ON r.child = a.ancestor
      WHERE a.level < 3
)
SELECT * FROM anc;
```

Modify and adapt that to your special case.